# What is ScaleTransform good for?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, size, scaletransform

why I should use ScaleX="2" for example instead of double the width of my control ??

```
<Button Width = "100" Content="Button1"/>


<Button Width = "50" Content="Button2">
   <Button.RenderTransform>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" />
   </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```

both buttons look exactly the same so again, what scale is good for

Comment: There are many scenarios where it is very useful. For example, I'm creating a Map-Server at the moment using a Canvas that initially has a size of 512x512. Every time I "zoom-in" I double the ScaleTransforms ScaleX and ScaleY and load new (smaller) images at the point where I zoomed in and at the deepest zoomlevel I have them all the way up to 2097152/2097152 and it works great 100% lag-free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if it was more complicated than a Button with a Width? What if you had a complex Path/Geometry, or maybe even a group of controls? You wouldn't want to go and manually change everything. What if you had a custom control, where you wanted to give one instance the size 100x100, and another instance 150x150? What if you were implementing zoom functionality (think google maps)?

In short, for your specific example, it doesn't provide much use. But there are many other cases where it does.

Answer (score 3):

Your concept of *"exactly the same"* seems to be different from mine.

[image: Screenshot]

The sizes you specify with `Width` and `Height` affect how much space the control takes up in the layout, this means that the control may take more or less space but the font size will stay the same for example. The [`RenderTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) is a manipulation on top of this which no longer concerns the layout and hence may distort the control.

> A render transform does not regenerate layout size or render size
>   information. Render transforms are typically intended for animating or
>   applying a temporary effect to an element. For example, the element
>   might zoom when focused or moused over, or might jitter on load to
>   draw the eye to that part of the user interface (UI).

---

See also the [`LayoutTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx) property, which does affect layout but still distorts the control.

Comment: but what about using image instead of button. then you won't see any difference at all. so when using Image object, is there any difference between using scale and change width and height??

Comment: Even with an Image you will see a difference on default settings since the Image control avoids stretching, if you apply a non-uniform scale-transform there **will** be stretching. See the references for the properties, they explain what they are for.

Answer (score 2):

It's useful when you don't have the ability to scale some parts of a control. Consider the DatePicker control. The default implementation has a drop-down calendar that was too small for my users' liking, so I introduced this snippet of XAML into my App.xaml file:

```
<Style TargetType="w:DatePicker">
    <Setter Property="CalendarStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="w:Calendar">
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now the calendar is 1.5 times as big, and my users are happy. There is no "CalendarWidth" or "CalendarHeight" property that I can set directly, so the `ScaleTransform` saved the day.